# Identifier defined by a combination of headers?

Tags: c++, opengl, header, undefined, identifier

Recently I ran into a identifier undefined error, but was surprised to find that it was because there were "two" imports missing, rather than one. I.E.

```
#include <a.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

would not compile because "foo" was undefined.

```
#include <b.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

also would not compile because "foo" was undefined.

however:

```
#include <a.h>
#include <b.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

was fine. I'm not sure how this is possible. Does anyone know what's going on here? Why is it that foo() is somehow defined by the combination of these two headers and not either of them individually?

For completeness, this happened during some fiddling with OpenGL on windows. the exact code that produced this behavior was:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    glClear(1);
}
```

where glClear was undefined if **either** of the two headers was missing. For clarity, the error in both cases was "Error: Identifier "glClear" is undefined"

Comment: If both errors were "glClear() is undefined", then the only way I could think of it happening is if the definition of glClear in the GL header was conditional on something that is defined in windows.h.  Might help to post the exact error in each case.

Comment: `gl/GL.h` probably has some dependency on a `#define` that `Windows.h` specifies. Usually it is considered a bad thing if correct functionality requires you to include header files in a specific order. Try defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` and/or `VC_EXTRALEAN` before including `Windows.h` and see if it still works. Won't be any huge revelation one way or the other, just out of personal interest.

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks for the prompt reply, the errors were identical. "Error: Identifier "glClear" is undefined" I'll update the question to be more specific. In the mean time, could you explain what you mean by"the definition of glClear in the GL header was conditional on something that is defined in windows.h"?

Comment: @Buddy I just tried to #define those but it doesn't seem to change anything in any combination.

Comment: @Solicasus - don't fret it, just put the header files in the order that they work and include a comment above it that "as of writing, correct functionality requires these files to be included in this order, change at your own risk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [preprocessor directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/), you can silently "hide" pieces of code in compile time.

For example, if a.h has:

```
#define A_INCLUDED
```

b.h may have:

```
#ifdef A_INCLUDED
void foo(void) { return; }
#endif
```

That way, b.h won't declare foo() unless a.h was included before.

I should look at those files to say for sure, but probably it's something like this.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Just out of curiosity, could you comment on whether or not doing something like this is common? or good/bad practice?

Comment: I've seen it in a lot of places and libraries. If it makes the header fail to compile, then it's misused, as <b.h> should include <a.h> itself if it's vital for compiling. But, for "addons", complementary functions, or optional modules, it's a good practice, as it allows to skip pieces of code which won't be used.

Comment: @Desaroll - agreed, good header design says they should be independent and self-contained - but with two big beasts OpenGL and Windows, there are bound to be version combinations where something slips thorugh

Comment: @Buddy Touché. It may be excusable for OpenGL. But if we don't remember that's a bad practice it may become more and more common.